# removing an unwanted page between two chapters

Tags: page-numbering, chapters

What could be the reason? Somehow a blank page with some random number gets inserted between two chapters.

```
\flushbottom
\include{chapter1}
\flushbottom
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{chapter2}
\flushbottom
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{chapter3}
\flushbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\flushbottom
\include{chapter4}
\flushbottom
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you add information about the class you're using?

Comment: `\flushbottom` is a declaration that affects all following pages, you only need issue it once.

Comment: With `twoside` layout (default for class `book`) chapters start at odd numbered pages and sometimes LaTeX needs to insert a page to ensure this.

Comment: Note what Heiko and David commented above. Besides, at the end of the chapter a `\cleardoublepage` is issued. An ugly method would be to use `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` in the beginning.

Comment: I tried `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` but it didn't work. Each chapter of my thesis produces a blank page before it starts. I'm using `book' class with `openany' and `oneside' options.

Answer (score 57):

### Class options `oneside`/`twoside`

With `twoside` layout (default for class `book`) chapters start at odd numbered pages and sometimes LaTeX needs to insert a page to ensure this.

If you do not want to have a `twoside` layout, it can be overwritten by option `oneside`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
```

### Class option `openany`

If the `twoside` layout should be kept, but a chapter can start on any page, then many classes support option `openany`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
```

### Redefining `\cleardoublepage`

The "ugly method" of [Harish Kumar's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111580/removing-an-unwanted-page-between-two-chapters/128336#comment246016_111580) would be to redefine `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
```

Comment: Is there an easy possibility to change this behavior only for some chapters? I want a `\cleardoublepage` for all normal chapters but not in the appendix.

Comment: @McLawrence Since there should not be normal chapters after the appendix, just move the redefinition `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` to the appendix.

Answer (score 1):

Unwanted one-page gap between two chapters can be eliminated using the syntax

```
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
```

Comment: This is already included in the answer by Heiko Oberdiek.  (But welcome to tex.sx.)

Answer (score 1):

I also had blank pages added randomly between chapters, but in my case, I solved this by removing "`\begin{flushleft}` and `\end{flushleft}`" from all chapters. In addition to this, I've added this command to my permeable file (master document) "`\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage`". I also added `\cleardoubleoddpage` and `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` to the master document.

This is my permeable file after the fix:

```
\cleardoubleoddpage
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\begin{document}

\include{01_Titel}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{02_danksagungen}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{03_Abstract}
\cleardoublepage{}

% Beendet eine Seite und erzwingt auf den nachfolgenden Seiten die Ausgabe aller Gleitobjekte (z.B. Abbildungen), die bislang definiert, aber noch nicht ausgegeben wurden. Dieser Befehl fügt, falls nötig, eine leere Seite ein, sodaß die nächste Seite nach den Gleitobjekten eine ungerade Seitennummer hat. 
% pagestyle für gesamtes Dokument aktivieren
\pagestyle{fancy}
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents
%Verzeichnis aller Abbildungen
\listoffigures
%Verzeichnis aller Tabellen
\listoftables
%\contentsline {chapter}{List of Tables}{iv}

\include{04_List_of_Symbols}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{05_List_of_Abbreviations}
\cleardoublepage{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{06_Introduction}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{07_State_of_the_Art}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{08_Theory}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{09_Methodology}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{10_Simulation_Results}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{11_Conclusion}
\cleardoublepage{}
\include{12_Appendix}
\cleardoublepage{}

%Literaturverzeichnis
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
%\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\bibliography{13_Literatur}


\end{document}
```

Comment: why did I get -1 reputation on this post ?

Comment: Not my downvote, but `\cleardoubleoddpage` doesn't make sense before the document begins.  All of those `\include` calls mean that no one else can really use your code.  `\cleardoublepage` shouldn't have `{}` after it.  So you have lots of not as relevant information, and the relevant bits are a bit strange.