# Force text between part and chapter to be on the next page after the part title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, page-breaking, parts

I have not found a better title sorry.

I have a document (book class) in which I have something like :

```
\part{MyPart}

The brief introduction of my part, where I present the three chapters I will have

\chapter{First Chapter}
```

As the introduction of my part is very short, I find it too much to loose too many pages. 
For now it is a structure of

- Page 1 : Part Name
- Page 2 : Blank
- Page 3 : Brief Introduction of my part
- Page 4 : Blank
- Page 5 : Chapter title and beginngin of my chapter

How do I skip some blank pages and get  :

- Part 1 : Part name
- Page 2 : Brief introduction
- Page 3 : Chapter title and beginning of my chapter ?

Comment: Adding `[oneside]` to class option should work, provided you can afford to make your book one sided.

Comment: Related to (or duplicate of)  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128336/14103.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own environment and modify `\@endpart` so it doesn't produce a blank page; I also provide a `\nopartintro` in case one of them has no introduction.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{\vfil\newpage}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{partintro}
  {\vspace*{\fill}
   \section*{\centering Introduction to part \thepart}
   \begin{quotation}}
  {\end{quotation}\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}
\newcommand{\nopartintro}{%
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\part{First}

\begin{partintro}
This is the introduction to the part

\lipsum[2]
\end{partintro}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Customize `partintro` as you like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify `\@endpart` to force a page break but no more.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\let\@endpart\clearpage
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{MyPart}

The brief introduction of my part, where I present the three chapters I will have

\chapter{First Chapter}

aaa

\end{document}
```